# Gradle includeBuild vs implementation project

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

What is the key difference between `includeBuild(...)` and `implementation(project(...))` in the Gradle build system? I cannot really see the usecase difference after reading the documentation:

1. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies
2. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#separate_composite

What I am trying to do: Share same codebase for two separate projects: data classes (kotlix.serialization), external database dao, interfaces. It is not a full library but just some code snippets.

How can I connect the two projects in Intellij so that type hinting works?

Comment: For me, `implementation(project(...))` is better. Each common component is just like a third-party library, making dependency graph more organized.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Composite Build** (by using `includeBuild`) is a way to create a dependency between autonomous Gradle Projects.
**Project import**, is a way to create a dependency between two modules within a same Gradle Project.

**Composite Build** is far more powerful and is also meant to be the new way of factorizing gradle configuration between multiple projects that you traditionally do with the `buildSrc` technique.
I found this ["Structuring Large Projects"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/structuring_software_products.html#defining_custom_project_types_as_convention_plugins) article to be easier to read than the ["Composite Builds"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) doc.

An excellent sample project that demonstrates the power of Composite Builds can be found in Gradle [sample_structuring_software_projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_structuring_software_projects.html).

### Project dependency case

The tree would look like this:

```
settings.gradle.kts
module1/build.gradle.kts
module2/build.gradle.kts
```

And you are declaring a dependency in `module1/build.gradle.kts` like this:

```kotlin
dependencies {
   implementation(project("com.domain:module2"))
}
```

The dependency will be resolved only if both projects are declared as sub-modules of a common root project.

It means you have a root `settings.gradle.kts` like this:

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "rootProject"
include(":module1")
include(":module2")
```

### Composite build case

The projects do not need to have common "umbrella" root project.
Each project is a totally independent project.

One project can simply declare a dependency on the other project (without even the target project knowing about it).

Tree:

```
project1/build.gradle.kts
project1/settings.gradle.kts
project2/build.gradle.kts
project2/settings.gradle.kts
```

In `project1/settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "project1"
includeBuild("../project2") //No more ':' as it is not a module
```

In `project2/settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "project2"
```

In `project1/build.gradle.kts` like this:

```kotlin
dependencies {
   implementation("com.domain:project2")
}
```

Comment: you're referencing the project2 prefixed with `com.domain:`. Where do you get that from?

Comment: There is a mistake in "Composite build case/build.gradle.kts/implementation" section.
It should be:

`dependencies{ implementation("com.domain:project2") }` . 

@AlejandroNavas, an `implementation` argument has to respect dependency notation pattern `group:name:version`, in the given example: `com.domain:project2` because version is empty.

Comment: I believe it was working fine like this at the time, but I am not sure. If you can point us the gradle doc about the correct usage of `project` it would be great, I could not find it.

Comment: `dependencies{ implementation("com.domain:project2") }` is correct. Also needs to be `includeBuild("../project2")` presuming that project1 and project2 are in the same folder.

Comment: @caeus, `com.domain` is the *group* defined in project2's build.gradle

Comment: I don't understand how to add a dependency on project2, could someone please make a github sample repo, and link it here?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Reading on the first link, the next para says:

> Local forks of module dependencies
>
> A module dependency can be substituted by a dependency to a local fork
>   of the sources of that module, if the module itself is built with
>   Gradle. This can be done by utilising composite builds. This allows
>   you, for example, to fix an issue in a library you use in an
>   application by using, and building, a locally patched version instead
>   of the published binary version. The details of this are described in
>   the section on composite builds.

So, it should be implementation project according to me.

P.S. The code completion is working on one of my sub project but not on the other. I am still trying to figure that out