# How to build a fat jar with multi-project and Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to *Gradle*, and is struggling with building a [multi-projects fat jar](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html).

I'm trying to do the same as mentioned here: [Gradle multiple jars from single source folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008324/gradle-multiple-jars-from-single-source-folder/20010200#20010200)

I have three packages, the dependency is: `PandaService` => `PandaServiceDataAccessLayer` =>  `PandaDatabaseDocker`.

Now I want to build a fat jar for `PandaService`. However, I'm not able to get  `./gradlew build` work. Now it is complaining that `Plugin with id 'org.springframework.boot' not found.` How can I fix it?

Will also appreciate any advises on changing `build.gradle` to follow the best practices.

#### More Info

This is the `settings.gradle` of `PandaService`:

```
rootProject.name = "PandaService"
include "PandaService"
include "PandaDatabaseDocker"
include "PandaServiceDataAccessLayer"
```

This is the `build.gradle` of `PandaService`:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

project(':PandaDatabaseDocker') {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir '../src'
                include 'PandaDatabaseDocker/**'
            }
        }
    }
}

project(':PandaServiceDataAccessLayer') {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir '../src'
                include 'PandaServiceDataAccessLayer/**'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':PandaDatabaseDocker')
    }
}

project(':PandaService') {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    group = 'PandaService'
    version = '0.0.1'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
    targetCompatibility = '11'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir '../src'
                include 'PandaService/**'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // Add depended local modules
        implementation project(':PandaServiceDataAccessLayer')

        // Spring boot + Jersey
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.4'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
        compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

        // Swagger
        implementation 'io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:1.6.5'

        // Lombok
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

        // log
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'


        // RDS Connection
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27'

        // AWS secretes manager
        implementation 'com.amazonaws.secretsmanager:aws-secretsmanager-jdbc:1.0.6'

        // JOOQ
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'

        // HikariCP
        implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.0.1'
    }

    //create a fat Jar with all dependencies
    jar {
        duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
        dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
        from {
            configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
        manifest {
            attributes "Main-Class": "com.PandaService.MainApplication"
        }
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        all*.exclude module: "logback-classic"

        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out.

The solution is to use Gradle Composite Builds. In this way, I don't even need to have a wrapper root project.

Reference:

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/10/intellij-idea-2016-3-eap-gradle-composite-builds-and-android-studio-2-2/
- [Gradle includeBuild vs implementation project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464719/gradle-includebuild-vs-implementation-project)
- https://docs.gradle.org/3.1/release-notes.html#composite-builds
- [Gradle includeBuild vs implementation project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464719/gradle-includebuild-vs-implementation-project)
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#defining_composite_builds